# Why Err is greater than Ok whilst Some is greater than None in Rust?

Tags: rust, language-lawyer

In Rust, the following is satisfied (as far as inner type(s) can be comparable):

- `Option::None` < `Option::Some(x)` for any `x`
- `Result::Ok(x)` < `Result::Err(y)` for any (`x`, `y`)

As both `Option` and `Result` just `#[derive(PartialOrd, Ord, PartialEq, Eq)]` ([source1](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/core/option.rs.html#515), [source2](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/core/result.rs.html#500)), the relationship above comes purely from the declaration order:

```rust
pub enum Result<T, E> {
    Ok(T),  //1st
    Err(E), //2nd
}
```

```rust
pub enum Option<T> {
    None,    //1st
    Some(T), //2nd
}
```

I personally feel some sort of inconsistency. In other words, to me, `None < Some` is very intuitive while `Ok` < `Err` is not.

Is there any advantage to make `Err` greater than `Ok`?

Comment: It's just how it is. It might have been more consistent for Result::Ok to behave more like Option::Some, but it can't be changed now. For most practical uses, the important thing is that the ordering _exists_ and is well-defined. It is pretty rare to actually use these `PartialOrd` impls explicitly.

Comment: I would counter this by asking if there is any case where you expect the ordering of `Ok` and `Err` to cause confusion for someone using a `Result`. For example, how did you come across this? I imagine the primary reason for `Result` even implementing `Ord` in the first place is just for ergonomics and so it can be used in more type of collections.

Comment: My personal opinion is that `Ok` < `Err` is more intuitive than the opposite, but the answer to "why" is probably as PeterHall suggests (that the ordering doesn't actually matter, just that one exists).

Comment: @Locke This question is about language design rather than practical situations. That's why I added a `#language-lawyer` tag. Though I do agree `Ok < Err` itself doesn't matter much, inconsistency forces programmers to *memorize* some rules. (cf: C++ is often criticized in that there are too many rules.)

Comment: @kmdreko Just for curiosity, why do you think so? Do you also think `Some < None` is more natural? The reason you have may be a hint to my original question; the language designer may have had the same reason as you.

Comment: @ynn I was imagining an ordered sequence of `Result`s and my intuition is that I'd assume `Ok`s would come first. Nothing more than that. Though I could see `Err` being less if you're used to `-1` return values for errors or using the mindset of "successes are better and therefore greater than failures" or something. I can see both ways. And no, I think `None` < `Some` makes more sense because the lack of value is more "empty" or more "zero" than a value, and therefore should be less.

Comment: *"forces programmers to memorize some rules"* - Only if they actually use this property. I haven't even known this is a thing; I would always filter them before sorting them. In what situation would this knowledge be relevant?